# Android App Layout Alignment issue with LG Nexus 4 and Moto X

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm facing a layout alignment issue with LG Nexus 4 and Moto X device. I want to align "About" button to the bottom of menu, But In the above devices navigation button covers it.
Take a look at screenshot:

[image]
[image]

Nexus 4 screenshot (Right) Other devices (Left)

Here is my code snippet.

```
//Upper Layout
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</FrameLayout>
//About Us button
```

**Possible Solution**
The work around to this problem is to hide navigation buttons tray. But I'm not satisfied with this.

**Note:** Above screenshots are taken at different periods of time so ignore the margin/dimension of layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can readjust your bottom padding based on the height of navigation bar.

```
int additionalPadding = 0;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Resources resources = getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        additionalPadding = resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
}
```

Now you can use add this additional padding to the bottom of your view.